# Unable to persist data into mysql database using spring + spring data jpa, Why?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am developing **Spring + JPA example**. In this example, I was able to find the `Product` based on `ProductCode`, but Unable to save Product using `Junit`. Please guide whats wrong in the code. I also I see that for each `junit` run the `auto_incremented` `product_id` is auto `increment`, but entity not getting saved.

**Note:** I followed many links from the stackoverflow, but nothing get worked for me.

**Product.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "product_code")
    private String productCode;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private float price;

    @Column(name = "vat")
    private float vat;

    @Transient
    @Formula("price * 2")
    private float totalPrice;

    @Column(name = "manufactured_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date manufacturedDate;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }

    public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return totalPrice;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public float getVat() {
        return vat;
    }

    public void setVat(float vat) {
        this.vat = vat;
    }

    public Date getManufacturedDate() {
        return manufacturedDate;
    }

    public void setManufacturedDate(Date manufacturedDate) {
        this.manufacturedDate = manufacturedDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product [id=" + id + ", productCode=" + productCode
                + ", productName=" + productName + ", price=" + price
                + ", vat=" + vat + ", manufacturedDate=" + manufacturedDate + "]";
    }
}
```

**ProductRepository.java**

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer>{
    Product findByProductCode(String productCode);
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="jpa-mysql-db" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.javamakeuse.entity.Product</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**database-context.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>    
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.javamakeuse.*"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <!-- Jpa Repositories -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.javamakeuse.repository" />

    <bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${mysql.driver.class.name}" />
        <property name="url" value="${mysql.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${mysql.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${mysql.username}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="${mysql.generate.ddl}" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="${mysql.dialect}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- ================= Entity Manager ===================== -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />

        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.scheduler.model" />

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>

        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="${mysq.persistent.unit.name}" />

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show.sql}</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- ==================== Transaction Manager ========================== -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**database.properties**

```
mysql.driver.class.name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
mysql.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
mysql.username=root
mysql.password=root
mysql.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

hibernate.show.sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
mysq.persistent.unit.name=jpa-mysql-db
mysql.generate.ddl=true
```

**db.sql**

```
create table product (
    product_id integer not null auto_increment, 
    manufactured_date datetime, 
    price float, 
    product_code varchar(255), 
    product_name varchar(255), 
    vat float, 
    primary key (product_id)
);

INSERT INTO product (manufactured_date,price,product_code,product_name,vat) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('03-03-2016', '%d-%m-%Y'), 130, 'AZ00010','IPhone-New-7', 5.6);
INSERT INTO product (manufactured_date,price,product_code,product_name,vat) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2016', '%d-%m-%Y'), 130, 'AZ00011','Lenovo Vibe X3', 5.6);
```

**application-context.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <import resource="database-context.xml"/>

</beans>
```

**ProductTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:application-context.xml")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
@Rollback
public class ProductTest {
    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    private SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository; 

    @Test
    public void testProductFinal() throws ParseException {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setManufacturedDate(SDF.parse("2016-08-08 01:01:01"));
        product.setPrice(200);
        product.setProductCode("AZ0100");
        product.setProductName("Lenovo Vibe X3");
        product.setVat(5.64F);

        productRepository.save(product);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByProductCode(){
        Product product = productRepository.findByProductCode("AZ00010");
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        System.out.println("ManufacturedDate  : "+product.getManufacturedDate());
        System.out.println("Price             : "+product.getPrice());
        System.out.println("ProductCode       : "+product.getProductCode());
        System.out.println("Product Name      : "+product.getProductName());
        System.out.println("Vat               : "+product.getVat());
    }
}
```

The below logger is saying that entity is inserted, but its not getting persisted into DB. Please help. I'm using MYSQL DB.

```
Hibernate: insert into product (manufactured_date, price, product_code, product_name, vat) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-data-jpa-version>1.9.2.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa-version>
        <hibernate-entitymanager-version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate-entitymanager-version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.39</mysql.version>
        <querydsl.version>4.1.3</querydsl.version>
        <camel.version>2.17.3</camel.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.7</logback.version>
        <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.21</jcl-over-slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring TEST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Entity Manager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-entitymanager-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- QueryDSL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MYSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logging Framework Logback, slf4j -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId> 
            <version>${jcl-over-slf4j.version}</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId> 
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId> <version>${logback.version}</version> 
            </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: You are using the Rollback annotation on your test class, causing anything 'inserted' to be rolledback when the test is done instead of committed.  This is per test, so data from one isn't available to use for testing in another.

Comment: `@Transactiona` by default does a rollback (in a test). You also have `@Rollback` which again enforces this. However next to that, your way of testing is flawed, your tests should be independent, your tests are dependent on each other. Could be that on an upgrade of jUnit your tests suddenlyu fail because of a changed order. The real issue here is not so much the rollback but your way of testing.

Comment: @Chris - Thank you !!. I also have one question apart from this issue and posting a separate Q soon. I see that `@Formula` annotation not working fine when I save the entity and return back the saved entity, but `@Formula` annotation not working when I'm returning it. For find it works fine.

Comment: Pls guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838933/formula-annotation-not-working-while-retriving-the-persisted-entity-in-same-ope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Chris. As per Chris suggestion we need to remove `@Rollback` which was causing anything 'inserted' to be rolled back when the test is done instead of committed. Apart from this we also need to remove the `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)` even when I tested only with `@Transactional`, it also not working. So simply use below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:application-context.xml")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class ProductTest {
    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    private SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @Test
    public void testProductFinal() throws ParseException {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setId(1);
        product.setManufacturedDate(SDF.parse("2016-08-08 01:01:01"));
        product.setPrice(200);
        product.setProductCode("AZ0100");
        product.setProductName("Lenovo Vibe X3");
        product.setVat(5.64F);

        productService.create(product);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByProductCode(){
        Product product = productService.findByProductCode("AZ00010");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("ManufacturedDate  : "+product.getManufacturedDate());
        System.out.println("Price             : "+product.getPrice());
        System.out.println("ProductCode       : "+product.getProductCode());
        System.out.println("Product Name      : "+product.getProductName());
        System.out.println("Vat               : "+product.getVat());
    }
}
```

Spring Declarative and Programatic transaction management are powerful and versatile. It works great. Proven here :)

```
mysql> select * from product;
+------------+---------------------+-------+--------------+----------------+------+
| product_id | manufactured_date   | price | product_code | product_name   | vat  |
+------------+---------------------+-------+--------------+----------------+------+
|          2 | 2016-03-03 00:00:00 |   130 | AZ00010      | IPhone-New-7   |  5.6 |
|          3 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |   130 | AZ00011      | Lenovo Vibe X3 |  5.6 |
|         14 | 2016-08-08 01:01:01 |   200 | AZ0100       | Lenovo Vibe X3 | 5.64 |
+------------+---------------------+-------+--------------+----------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```