# @Formula annotation not working while retriving the persisted entity in same operation, why?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm using `Spring + Spring Data JPA` example. In this using `@Formula` annotation to do some processing on data post retrieval from DB. In my project, each Entity `@Formula` annotation is meant for the different different purposes. Here I'd like to understand the concept as I dont find any useful yet.
- Using repository `save()` method I'm persisting the entity into the DB, now in that operation only I wanted my persisted entity to be return back, while doing the entity return `@Formula` annotation not doing the job why ?   Lets see the code.

**Product.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "product_code")
    private String productCode;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private float price;

    @Column(name = "vat")
    private float vat;

    @Formula("price * 2")
    private float totalPrice;

    @Column(name = "manufactured_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date manufacturedDate;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }

    public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return totalPrice;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public float getVat() {
        return vat;
    }

    public void setVat(float vat) {
        this.vat = vat;
    }

    public Date getManufacturedDate() {
        return manufacturedDate;
    }

    public void setManufacturedDate(Date manufacturedDate) {
        this.manufacturedDate = manufacturedDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product [id=" + id + ", productCode=" + productCode
                + ", productName=" + productName + ", price=" + price
                + ", vat=" + vat + ", manufacturedDate=" + manufacturedDate + "]";
    }
}
```

**ProductRepository.java**

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer>{
    Product findByProductCode(String productCode);
}
```

**ProductService.java**

```
public interface ProductService {
    void create(Product product);
    Product findByProductCode(String productCode);
}
```

**ProductServiceImpl.java**

```
@Transactional
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Override
    public void create(Product product) {
        productRepository.save(product);
    }

    @Override
    public Product findByProductCode(String productCode) {
        return productRepository.findByProductCode(productCode);
    }
}
```

**ProductTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:application-context.xml")
public class ProductTest {
    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    private SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @Test
    public void testProductFinalAndGet() throws ParseException {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setId(1);
        product.setManufacturedDate(SDF.parse("2016-08-08 10:10:15"));
        product.setPrice(400);
        product.setProductCode("AZ0111");
        product.setProductName("Nokia Lumia");
        product.setVat(5.64F);

        Product p = productRepository.save(product);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("ManufacturedDate  : "+p.getManufacturedDate());
        System.out.println("Price             : "+p.getPrice());
        System.out.println("ProductCode       : "+p.getProductCode());
        System.out.println("Product Name      : "+p.getProductName());
        System.out.println("Vat               : "+p.getVat());
    }


    @Test
    public void testFindByProductCode(){
        Product product = productService.findByProductCode("AZ00010");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("ManufacturedDate  : "+product.getManufacturedDate());
        System.out.println("Price             : "+product.getPrice());
        System.out.println("ProductCode       : "+product.getProductCode());
        System.out.println("Product Name      : "+product.getProductName());
        System.out.println("Vat               : "+product.getVat());
    }
}
```

Result of testProductFinalAndGet():

```
Hibernate: select product0_.product_id as product_1_0_0_, product0_.manufactured_date as manufact2_0_0_, product0_.price as price3_0_0_, product0_.product_code as product_4_0_0_, product0_.product_name as product_5_0_0_, product0_.vat as vat6_0_0_, product0_.price * 2 as formula0_0_ from product product0_ where product0_.product_id=?
Hibernate: insert into product (manufactured_date, price, product_code, product_name, vat) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
----------------------------------------
ManufacturedDate  : Mon Aug 08 10:10:15 IST 2016
Price             : 0.0
ProductCode       : AZ0111
Product Name      : Nokia Lumia
Vat               : 5.64


Result of testFindByProductCode()

Hibernate: select product0_.product_id as product_1_0_, product0_.manufactured_date as manufact2_0_, product0_.price as price3_0_, product0_.product_code as product_4_0_, product0_.product_name as product_5_0_, product0_.vat as vat6_0_, product0_.price * 2 as formula0_ from product product0_ where product0_.product_code=?
----------------------------------------
ManufacturedDate  : 2016-03-03 00:00:00.0
Price             : 260.0
ProductCode       : AZ00010
Product Name      : IPhone-New-7
Vat               : 5.6
```

So looks like for `save()` operation, @Formula not working fine why ?  Please guide.

```
mysql> select * from product;
+------------+---------------------+-------+--------------+----------------+------+
| product_id | manufactured_date   | price | product_code | product_name   | vat  |
+------------+---------------------+-------+--------------+----------------+------+
|         17 | 2016-03-03 00:00:00 |   130 | AZ00010      | IPhone-New-7   |  5.6 |
|         18 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |   140 | AZ00011      | Lenovo Vibe X3 |  5.6 |
|         19 | 2016-08-08 10:10:15 |   400 | AZ0111       | Nokia Lumia    | 5.64 |
+------------+---------------------+-------+--------------+----------------+------+
```

**EDIT**
If I used below

```
@Test
    public void testProductFinalAndGet() throws ParseException {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setId(1);
        product.setManufacturedDate(SDF.parse("2016-08-08 10:10:15"));
        product.setPrice(400);
        product.setProductCode("AZ0111");
        product.setProductName("Nokia Lumia");
        product.setVat(5.64F);

        Product p = productRepository.saveAndFlush(product);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("ManufacturedDate  : "+p.getManufacturedDate());
        System.out.println("Price             : "+p.getPrice());
        System.out.println("ProductCode       : "+p.getProductCode());
        System.out.println("Product Name      : "+p.getProductName());
        System.out.println("Vat               : "+p.getVat());
    }
```

Here is the result:

---

```
Hibernate: select product0_.product_id as product_1_0_0_, product0_.manufactured_date as manufact2_0_0_, product0_.price as price3_0_0_, product0_.product_code as product_4_0_0_, product0_.product_name as product_5_0_0_, product0_.vat as vat6_0_0_, product0_.price * 2 as formula0_0_ from product product0_ where product0_.product_id=?
Hibernate: insert into product (manufactured_date, price, product_code, product_name, vat) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
----------------------------------------
ManufacturedDate  : Mon Aug 08 10:10:15 IST 2016
Price             : 0.0
ProductCode       : AZ0111
Product Name      : Nokia Lumia
Vat               : 5.64
```

**EDIT-2**

---

I tried many options:

```
Product p = productRepository.saveAndFlush(product);
em.refresh(p);
```

Another

```
Product p = productRepository.saveAndFlush(product);
em.flush();
em.refresh(p);
```

But getting below error:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:275)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.javamakeuse.test.ProductTest.testProductFinalAndGet(ProductTest.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: The formula is a SQL expression, that is executed when the entity is read from the database using a select statement. Your test never executes any SQL statement: it just creates an entity in memory and persists it. So the formula is never executed. Why don't you just remove the totalPrice field and add a getTotalPrice() method returning price * 2. That will always work fine.

Comment: Thanks. I've to do some decryption of fields (such as Credit Card, SSN etc) from another Entity classes, so use of `@Formula` make sense (keeping same for consistency in an application). Also I'm using JPA Repository query, `JPQL (CriteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder)`, so `@Formula` annotation helps. Now In my stated scenario, how can I get `@Formula` to be applied on persisted entity while retrieving? I desperately needs to do this somehow. Pls guide.

Comment: Call flush() after the save, then refresh the entity.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#flush--

Comment: Have you refreshed the entity after the flush, i.e. called EntityManager.refresh() on that entity?

Comment: So you haven't called refresh().

Comment: Yes, you have one. You can inject it use `@PersistenceContext`. You can also create custom methods in repositories, as explained in the documentation. You can even create a custom base class that all your repositories will extend, as also explained in the documentation.

Comment: Still issues, See EDIT-2. I'm not clear how we can use EntityManager with Repository ?

Comment: Take a step back, and **read the documentation of spring-data-jpa**.

Comment: Right, persisted entity is returning, but I dont see `@Formula` annotation doing the job here, in this particular use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to this problem. I made some arrangement (or you can say checkl) in Product model class which would check `return totalPrice == 0.0 ? price : totalPrice;`. This solved the problem of when I'm persisting an Entity into DB, same I'm returring back with the `@Formula` annotation working.

**Product.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "product_code")
    private String productCode;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private float price;

    @Column(name = "vat")
    private float vat;

    @Formula("price * 2")
    private float totalPrice;

    @Column(name = "manufactured_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date manufacturedDate;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }

    public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return totalPrice == 0.0 ? price : totalPrice;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public float getVat() {
        return vat;
    }

    public void setVat(float vat) {
        this.vat = vat;
    }

    public Date getManufacturedDate() {
        return manufacturedDate;
    }

    public void setManufacturedDate(Date manufacturedDate) {
        this.manufacturedDate = manufacturedDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product [id=" + id + ", productCode=" + productCode
                + ", productName=" + productName + ", price=" + price
                + ", vat=" + vat + ", manufacturedDate=" + manufacturedDate + "]";
    }
}
```

[image]

@JB Nizet - I was still unable to make that working using `EntityManager` using flush or refresh etc. Any code snippet would help.